# Server is receiving data via API endpoint but ignoring it when creating a record (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, api-design

I'm setting up an API endpoint for a create action, and then posting to it from another application to create a db record.

But data posted to the endpoint is being ignored when creating a record.

In the below code, `Application 1` is using a rake task to post to `Application 2`.

**Application 1**

```
task post_this: :environment do
  require 'rest-client'
  p RestClient.post "site.io/api/v1/users", {:first_name => "Long", :last_name => "John Silver", :email => "1@example.com"}
end
```

**Application 2**

Schema

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "password"
  t.string   "password_confirmation"
  t.string   "temp_password"
  t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
end
```

UsersController

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.temp_password = Devise.friendly_token
    respond_to do |format|
        if @user.save
            format.json { render json: @user, status: :created }
            format.xml { render xml: @user, status: :created }
        else
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.xml { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

Routes

```
namespace :api do    
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users, :defaults => { :format => 'xml' }  
  end
end
```

**Response in Application 1 making request**

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<user>\n  <id type=\"integer\">6</id>\n  <first-name nil=\"true\"/>\n  <last-name nil=\"true\"/>\n  <email nil=\"true\"/>\n  <password nil=\"true\"/>\n  <password-confirmation nil=\"true\"/>\n  <temp-password>BzXXpW4wCM5ydhpYxzMg</temp-password>\n  <created-at type=\"dateTime\">2016-05-27T09:14:32Z</created-at>\n  <updated-at type=\"dateTime\">2016-05-27T09:14:32Z</updated-at>\n</user>\n"
```

**Application 2 Heroku logs**

```
Parameters: {"first_name"=>"Long", "last_name"=>"John Silver", "email"=>"1@example.com"}
Started POST "/api/v1/users" for 104.155.210.3 at 2016-05-27 09:14:32 +0000
(1.0ms)  BEGIN2016-05-SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("temp_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["temp_password", "BzXXpW4wCM5ydhpYxzMg"], ["created_at", "2016-05-27 09:14:32.759178"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-27 09:14:32.759178"]]
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
(2.0ms)  COMMIT
Completed 201 Created in 43ms (Views: 16.1ms | ActiveRecord: 12.7ms)
```

A record is being created but most of the columns are nil.

I'm just learning how to setup API endpoints so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Comment: version => ruby 2.3.0p0

Comment: Sorry I mean Ruby on Rails version not Ruby.

Comment: Version Rails 4.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `users_controller.rb` after your actions add:

```
private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :temp_password)
end
```

and update your new action to use `user_params` instead of `params[:user]` like so:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```